# use d3.json instead of d3.csv to create bubble chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use following code to create a bubble chart:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269
This code uses this for loading a csv file:

```
d3.csv("flare.csv", function(d) {
  d.value= +d.value;
  if (d.value) return d;
}, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

I would like to load a json file instead, so I wrote this:

```
d3.json("data1.php", function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(data) {
        data.value= +data.value;
    });
    if (d.value) return d;
    },function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

the output of php file is this:

```
[{"disease":"Cold","value":"33"},{"disease":"Anemia","value":"23"},{"disease":"Hepatitis B","value":"21"},{"disease":"Gum disease","value":"19"},{"disease":"Lung Cancer","value":"17"},{"disease":"Diarrhea","value":"15"},{"disease":"Strep Throat","value":"13"},{"disease":"STDs","value":"11"},{"disease":"Heart Disease","value":"8"},{"disease":"Type 2 Diabetes","value":"6"}]
```

for some reason my code (using d3.json ...) is not working. and I just get a blank page. I really appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `d3.csv`, `d3.json` does **not** accept an accessor function.

So, instead of this:

```
d3.json("data1.php", function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(data) {
        data.value= +data.value;
    });
    if (d.value) return d;
    }, function(error, classes) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

It should be this:

```
d3.json("data1.php", function(error, classes) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

And do your `forEach` with `classes` inside the callback.